# Globally setting module paths

Tags: python, macos, path

After I install Python modules using pip3, they install to my site-packages sub folder in my python3.7 folder.

When beginning a new Python project, I have to set the path each time like so:

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
```

I thought simply add the following to the terminal would solve this problem

```
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/":"${PYTHONPATH}"
export PYTHONPATH
```

However, this does not seem to resolve the problem. I continue to receive the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'X'
```

I appreciate any help on this basic task, as I am not very familiar with the terminal environment.

Comment: do you use `Python3.7` to run code ? Python 3.7 should have this path in `sys.path`. Check what you have in `sys.path` already. Maybe you try to run it with different Python - ie. 2.7, 3.6. . Then you should use `pip2.7` or `pip3.6` to install it.

Comment: you didn't load python with Anaconda did you?

Comment: @jmh Actually yes, I use the Spyder IDE which I open through the anaconda navigator. Will this have an affect?

Comment: @furas Yes, always Python 3.7 to run code. And yes, the above path is not present when I check the contents of sys.path. I was hoping my simple terminal two liner would solve this, yet I have to do sys.path.append within my scripts each time.

Answer (score 0):

To load modules in Anaconda you should never use the pip3 command. Use `conda install module_name`. So in your case, I'd try reinstalling the module using that command.

Comment: I try to use conda wherever possible. But is it not true to say that some modules are not possible to be installed via conda?

Comment: Thats not what I said.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - I know you didn't say that.